# Get only PID from tasklist using cmd title

Tags: windows, cmd, title, pid, tasklist

Desired output:

```
1234
```

Just the PID. Nothing else - no other characters, numbers, or symbols.

I'm trying to run `tasklist` so it gives me only the PID of a named or titled process.

`tasklist | findstr /i "cmd.exe"` is the closest I've gotten, but the result is too verbose. I just want the PID number.

Bonus points for linking me a description of what the tasklist filter operators mean - "eq", "ne", etc, since they aren't anywhere in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist).

Comment: Yes, i have the exact same problem but i could nt get it to work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difficult thing with `tasklist` is its default output format. For example, when command line:

```cmd
tasklist /FI "ImageName eq cmd.exe" /FI "Status eq Running"
```

is executed, we get:

> ```cmd
> Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
> ========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
> cmd.exe                      12740 Console                    1      3'328 K
> cmd.exe                      11020 Console                    1      3'304 K
> ```

Unless the column widths are fixed, which I would not rely on, extracting the PID is not that trivial, because the image name could also have <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> in it, so using such as delimiters would not work.
A possible way was to count the number of `=`-signs in the second line up to the first <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, so we know the number of characters to truncate to have the image name removed, but this requires some kind of loop (using `goto`), so the performance might be quite bad.

However, there are other output formats available for `tasklist`. The command line:

```cmd
tasklist /FI "ImageName eq cmd.exe" /FI "Status eq Running" /FO CSV
```

results in this output:

> ```cmd
> "Image Name","PID","Session Name","Session#","Mem Usage"
> "cmd.exe","12740","Console","1","3'328 K"
> "cmd.exe","11020","Console","1","3'304 K"
> ```

Now it is quite easy to extract the PID:

```cmd
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%R in ('
    tasklist /FI "ImageName eq cmd.exe" /FI "Status eq Running" /FO CSV /NH
') do (
    set "FLAG1=" & set "FLAG2="
    for %%C in (%%R) do (
        if defined FLAG1 (
            if not defined FLAG2 (
                echo %%~C
            )
            set "FLAG2=#"
        )
        set "FLAG1=#"
    )
)
```

Another output formats is used by the following command line:

```cmd
tasklist /FI "ImageName eq cmd.exe" /FI "Status eq Running" /FO LIST
```

resulting in this output:

> ```cmd
> Image Name:   cmd.exe
> PID:          12740
> Session Name: Console
> Session#:     1
> Mem Usage:    3'328 K
>
> Image Name:   cmd.exe
> PID:          11020
> Session Name: Console
> Session#:     1
> Mem Usage:    3'304 K
> ```

With this it is even simpler to get the desired output:

```cmd
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2" %%K in ('
   tasklist /FI "ImageName eq cmd.exe" /FI "Status eq Running" /FO LIST ^| findstr /B "PID:"
') do (
   echo %%K
)
```

By the way, for the filter options `/FI`, there are the following operators available:

- `eq` -- equal to;
- `ne` -- not equal to;
- `gt` -- greater than;
- `lt` -- less than;
- `ge` -- greater than or equal to;
- `le` -- less than or equal to;

The Microsoft documentation as well as the help message (`tasklist /?`) do not explain their meaning, but I found the following external resources:

- [Managing Windows Programs from the Command Line: Tasklist](https://commandwindows.com/tasklist.htm)
- [Microsoft DOS tasklist command](https://www.computerhope.com/tasklist.htm)

Comment: `$ tasklist /FI "ImageName eq cmd.exe" /FI "Status eq Running" /FO CSV` 
INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.
And `tasklist /?` shows the filter options like the documentation does, but neither one shows what "eq", "ge", "le" etc mean. That's what I was asking.

Comment: See my edit -- the operators are now explained. Concerning the return message you mentioned (`INFO:`): type `tasklist` without any filter options and check whether or not the tasks you want are listed, then add one filter option after another and heck again...

Comment: Well explained with syntax everything

Comment: The second part is very convenient for iterating through PID of processes that correspond to a particular ImageName.

Answer (score 6):

Use `for /f` to parse output. The PID is the 2nd column space separated.
The default separator/delmiter is the space, adjacent delims count as one.

So this sample ouput:

```
> tasklist | findstr /i "cmd.exe"
cmd.exe                      14924 Console                    9         6.008 K
```

Is parsed on the cmd line

```
for /f "tokens=2" %A in ('tasklist ^| findstr /i "cmd.exe" 2^>NUL') do @Set "PID=%A"
```

Or in a batch:

```
@Echo off & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PID="
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('tasklist ^| findstr /i "cmd.exe" 2^>NUL') do @Set "PID=!PID!,%%A"
if defined PID Echo cmd.exe has PID(s) %PID:~1%
```

> cmd.exe has PID(s) 14924,11268,3652

The last one presumably the temporary one used by the `for /f` itself.

---

#### **EDIT** late addition to my answer.

The tool [cmdow](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/) from Ritchie Lawrence can accomplish your task.

With this question open in firefox:

```
> cmdow.exe "get only PID from task*" /f
Handle  Lev Pid -Window status- Image    Caption
0x0103DE 1 9532 Max Ina Ena Vis firefox  Get only PID from tasklist using cmd title - Stack Overflow - Mozilla Firefox
```

To only get the PID on cmd line

```
> for /f "tokens=3" %A in ('cmdow.exe "get only PID from task*" /B /F') Do @Echo:%A
9532
```

In a batch file double the percent signs `%%A`.

Demonstration using `start` to run another cmd.exe with a specified title:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\27\SO_50555929_2.cmd
@Echo off
set "MyTitle=This is a quite long title to distinguish from other"
start "%MyTitle%" cmd.exe /k cmdow.exe @ /F

:: wait to get other cmd instance get started
timeout /t 3 >NUL

set "PID="
for /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('cmdow.exe "%MyTitle%*"') do set "PID=%%A"
if defined PID Echo %PID%
```

Comment: Neither one of those does what I want.

Comment: This wasnt for me either. :c

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are expecting. There could be several `cmd` shells running. If they are running a program, their window title typically changes.

It is easy enough to get the cmd processes and there PID (the Id field). The window title is also available.

```
PS C:\src\t\s1> Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -eq 'cmd' }

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    152      15    10280      16432      10.80   2808   1 cmd
    153      13     8472      12220       3.68   7232   1 cmd

PS C:\src\t\s1> Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -eq 'cmd' } | ForEach-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle }
cmd.exe
dirlist.bat (C:\src\t) - VIM
```

Getting the PID only to appear is easy enough. But, which one do you want?

```
PS C:\src\t\s1> Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -eq 'cmd' } | ForEach-Object { $_.Id }
2808
7232
```

Comment: In Admin CMD: `'PS' is not recognized as an internal or external command`
In Admin PS: `Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Get-Process`
The plan is to use a titled CMD window, like `TITLE test`, and then find it that way.

Comment: When you say 'title', it sounds like you mean 'Image name' (i.e. blah.exe).  Also, the command starts at `Get-Process`, not `PS`

Comment: 'Title' means the text in the system bar at the top of the window. It is not the executable image name. `(Get-Process) | Where-Object { $null -ne $_.MainWindowTitle -and '' -ne $_.MainWindowTitle } | % { $_.MainWindowTitle }`